# ldapsearch filter starts with exclamation mark

Tags: filter, ldap

I need the syntax for an ldap search query that gives me the results for any object with and attribute called sambantpassword that starts with an exclamation point.

So far I have:

```
sambantpassword=!*
```

This does not return any results. I know I can use an exclamation point directly in the query because `sambantpassword=!` returns a test entry that has `!` as the sambantpassword.

Comment: Rather strange to be searching on password values, indeed dubious.

Comment: @EJP, do you care to expound? Some software (https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa) puts an exclamation point in front of the encrypted password in order to disable/lock the account.